# Set Property of Each Item In Object Array (C#, Regex.Split())

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, object, split

I am trying to use the Regex.Split method to set a property of each item in an object array to the results of the split method. Consider the following class with getters and setters:

```
public class PuffAndStuff
    {
        private String puff = "";
        public string puff { get => puff; set => puff = value; }
    }
```

The deal is, I want to separate the text in a text file with a Regex.Split method. Consider the following program:

```
static void Main()
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(@"Puff[0-9]\r\n");

            PuffAndStuff[] subPuff = new PuffAndStuff[] { new PuffAndStuff { puff = "" } };


            StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("D:\\SampleText.txt");

            string check = reader.ReadToEnd();

            string[] arrayCheck = Regex.Split(check, @"Puff[0-9]\r\n");

            subPuff = Regex.Split(check, @"Puff[0-9]\r\n");

            subPuff[0].puff = arrayCheck[1] + arrayCheck[2];

            Console.WriteLine("Segment 1:\r\n" + subPuff[0].puff);


            Console.WriteLine("Segment 2:\r\n" + arrayCheck[3] + arrayCheck[4]);


        }
```

The thought has crossed my mind that it would probably be much better to separate text from a file in a different way (use a generic dynamic list instead of an object array) but I'm also trying to think of the fastest way to do this (making the object list/dictionary/array as static as "possible"). Perhaps this is not a practical way to approach it, though. My one problem is that the subPuff object array won't accept the Regex.Split() string. Does anyone have suggestions on either how I can make this work, or how I can make this even better?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve here. Can you share with us what you are ultimately looking for, regardless of the solution you currently have?

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to break a file into different segments and store them as objects. I want to do this so that each object can be reviewed for missing text or data. Let's just say this is part of an upcoming project I have. I want to be able to make a list of objects missing different segments so that one doesn't have to scroll through a text file to see what is missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Regex works for me. Check your text file for hidden characters like maybe a space at the end of the line. Unsure exactly what you are after but I got rid of one of the arrays because you defined it with one element and then tried to push in the results of the .Split. It will not resize by itself but a List will. Also you tried to put a string into a PuffAndStuff object. That won't work. Anyway, maybe something in my code will help.

Remember the programmer who had a problem because he had to manipulate some text. He thought "I will use Regex!" Then he had two problems. :-)

```
public class PuffAndStuff
        {
            private String puff = "";
            //Naming viloation - changed puff to Puff
            public string Puff { get => puff; set => Puff = value; }
        }

 private void OPCode()
        {
            StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(@"D:\\SampleText.txt");
            string check = reader.ReadToEnd();
            List<PuffAndStuff> lstPuff = new List<PuffAndStuff>();
            string[] arrayCheck = Regex.Split(check, @"Puff[0-9]\r\n");
            foreach(string s in arrayCheck)
            {
                lstPuff.Add(new PuffAndStuff { Puff = s });
            }
            lstPuff[0].Puff = arrayCheck[1] + arrayCheck[2];
            Console.WriteLine("Segment 1:\r\n" + lstPuff[0].Puff);
            Console.WriteLine("Segment 2:\r\n" + arrayCheck[3] + arrayCheck[4]);
        }
```

Comment: I was afraid you'd introduce a for-like loop as a solution - was hoping to just split. But hey, we can't have it all, right? I thought of changing that to a list too - I was JUST doing that before you posted your answer, which I seriously appreciate. Thanks a ton! :)